# AngularJS Multi-Step Form Using UI-Router (With Navigation Links)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I followed this tutorial to implement my own multi-step form: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

The problem here is this only works if your page is the form page only and nothing else. I currently have a SPA that has four pages, one of which is the registration form.

- Home
- Registration
- Mechanics
- Terms & Conditions

My `index.php`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav home">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="registration">Registration</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="mechanics">Mechanics</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="terms-conditions">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!-- .container-fluid -->

  <div ui-view=""></div><!-- load contents via angular views -->

</div><!-- .container -->
```

I am using ui-router to navigate through these pages. This works okay. I tried to use ui-router within the Registration page with nested views, but apparently it does not behave as expected. I want the Registration Page to load the first nested view, but it does not bind with it. Here are my nested views:

- registration-profile.php (should be the default view)
- registration-artist.php (step 2)
- registration-share.php (final step)

Here is my stateProvider code mixing the two (navigation and registration nested views):

```
spinnrApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.php"
    })
    .state('registration', {
      url: "/registration",
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/registration.php",
      controller: "RegController"
    })
    .state('registration.profile', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/profile", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-profile.php"
    })
    .state('registration.artist', { // nested state for the registration form
      url: "/artist", // url will be nested /registration/artist
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-artist.php"
    })
    .state('registration.share', { // each nested state will have their own view
      url: "/share", // url will be nested /registration/share
      templateUrl: "app/components/registration/partials/registration-share.php"
    })
    .state('mechanics', {
      url: "/mechanics",
      templateUrl: "app/components/mechanics/mechanics.php"
    })
    .state('terms-conditions', {
      url: "/terms-conditions",
      templateUrl: "app/components/terms/terms-conditions.php"
    });
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

This is what registration.php looks like:

```
<form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
  <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
  <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
</form>
```

For some reason, the 'ui-view' is not binding with registration-profile.php, which should be the default view once the page is visited. What seems to be the issue here? Am I doing something wrong that I am not aware of? I am currently just learning AngularJS, btw.

Answer (score 0):

ScotchDesign have supplied a Plunk of the code your code is based o, http://plnkr.co/edit/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC?p=preview

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/registration');
```

Also, the default view is the one that is set with '/', i.e. the 'home' state, if you want to have the 'registration' view be the first then you could either: change 'home' to have the url '/home', and have a 'stateEngine' service call $state.go based on some criteria, or set 'registration's url to be '/'.